# UV Islands should be identical but are different when unwrapped

Tags: uv

I've unwrapped a model and 2 islands that should look the same don't. I want to straighten the left side out to look like right side island. Any tips on how I may go about this?

I have UV Tool kit and UV Packmaster 2 add ons if thats any help.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). The first island has some stretching visible, you probably didn't mark all the same seams before unwrapping.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look :)